# How do I load a javascript library in Rhino, from a server that uses gzip encoding?

Tags: javascript, gzip, rhino, content-encoding

In rhino, I'm used to being able to load javascript libraries from a URL, e.g.

```
load('http://latex.mathoverflow.net/mathjax/MathJax.js')
```

(This doesn't actually work, unless you provide a browser-like environment first, via env.js or similar. But rhino manages to get the file, and start compiling it.)

However, if the server provides the javascript library gzipped, rhino seems to fail immediately with syntax errors, e.g.

```
load('http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js')
```

You can see the difference using curl, e.g.

```
curl --head http://latex.mathoverflow.net/mathjax/MathJax.js
```

gives

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 May 2011 21:07:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Fri, 07 Jan 2011 05:13:36 GMT
ETag: "24b8044-9db7-4993aae2a4000"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 40375
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

while

```
curl --head http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
```

gives

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 08 May 2011 20:06:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Mar 2011 17:30:00 GMT
ETag: "3f59e66-a250-49e608b6bf600"-gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Content-Length: 12466
Age: 3624
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
X-Amz-Cf-Id: d0e2d89a0d90c9b7bb49b466e233b005389f96db378543b01de51769589f84dfd9733430f773846f
Via: 1.0 fee706bb2dcbccabb9a09a17e9d6037c.cloudfront.net:11180 (CloudFront), 1.0 6d5d46d2c7dcee5d4601d83b29b92a90.cloudfront.net:11180 (CloudFront)
Connection: close
```

Any suggestions? Is there a trick to allow rhino to load gzipped scripts?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656201) for this.